# Access VBA To run multiple select queries and export to excel on different worksheets

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to export multiple queries to the same excel worksheet and name the excel worksheet.  I can get it to export to multiple worksheets in the same spreadsheet but not the same one.

Option Compare Database

```
Sub validate()

Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim strFolder As String
Dim rst1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim qry1 As String
Dim qry2 As String

qry1 = "SELECT DISTINCT IIf(IsDate([models].[startdate])=False,'No' + '  ' + [models.Startdate],'Yes') AS StartDate, IIf(IsDate([models].[Enddate])=False," & _
            "'No' + '  ' + [models.Enddate],'Yes') AS EndDate FROM [Models]"
 db.CreateQueryDef "temp1", qry1



qry2 = "SELECT DISTINCT Left([pages.imagefile],InStr([pages.imagefile],'_')-1) AS Pages_Series, " & _
       "Left([parts.imagefile],InStr([parts.imagefile],'_')-1) AS Parts_ImgSeries, IIf([Pages_Series]=[Parts_ImgSeries],'Yes','No') AS Expr1 FROM [Pages], [Parts]"

 db.CreateQueryDef "temp2", qry2



strFolder = CurrentProject.Path & "\"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "temp1", strFolder & "Validated.xlsx", True
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "temp2", strFolder & "Validated.xlsx", True

  CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "temp1"
  CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "temp2"

End Sub
```

This will put both queries into 2 different worksheets but I need them both in the same worksheet. Also how to name the worksheet too.

Comment: How should they appear in the same worksheet? Side by side? One above the other?

Comment: one above the other

Answer (score 0):

Create the worksheet in the file and create two *Named Range*s in this.

Name these as, say, *NamedRangeName1* and *NamedRangeName2*.

Then run:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "temp1", strFolder & "Validated.xlsx", True, "NamedRangeName1"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "temp2", strFolder & "Validated.xlsx", True, "NamedRangeName2"
```

Comment: I am a noob to this and pieced this together so i apologize but how would that look?

Comment: You would probably have to open Excel and create the workbook, worksheet, and names ranges via automation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for the results of the queries to be output *one above the other* in the worksheet, I might suggest altering your SQL to combine the results of the two queries using a `union`, and then output the results of this **single** query to a spreadsheet:

```
select distinct 
    IIf(IsDate([models].[startdate])=False,'No  ' & [models.Startdate],'Yes') as StartDate, 
    IIf(IsDate([models].[Enddate])=False,'No  ' & [models.Enddate],'Yes') as EndDate,
    null as Expr1
from 
    [Models]
union all
select distinct 
    Left([pages.imagefile],InStr([pages.imagefile],'_')-1) as Pages_Series, 
    Left([parts.imagefile],InStr([parts.imagefile],'_')-1) as Parts_ImgSeries, 
    IIf([Pages_Series]=[Parts_ImgSeries],'Yes','No') as Expr1 
from 
    [Pages], [Parts]
```

I would also suggest using the **ampersand operator** (`&`) for concatenation, as this will always treat the arguments as strings, whereas the addition operator (`+`) will first attempt to interpret the numerical content of the data before resorting to concatenation if the data is non-numerical.

Comment: My goal is to eventually add around 20 queries that check various things. Is there a way to combine them all with union? Better way to group mutiple queries together by declaring the variables together to one variable such as qry1 and qry2 = to qry3?

Comment: Using this method, all queries must have the same number of columns of the same data types, so 20 unioned queries may not be a viable solution. With that said, if the queries are outputting different data, why would you want them above one another as opposed to in separate worksheets/workbooks?

Comment: These are going to be queries that validate propagation between tables and other things to make sure there are no errors.  It would be easier if all errors could show on one worksheet especially if there are like 20 queries.